# mysql query ironing one search result on webpage?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

My query printed on webpage

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE (product_name like '%meat%' OR description like '%meat%' OR ingradients like '%meat%') AND hide!=1 ORDER BY id ASC
```

If I run the same query query in mysql its showing 2 results with my php loop code its showing only one result,

my php code

```
<?php       

$keyword=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Keyword']);

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE (product_name like '%$keyword%' OR description like '%$keyword%' OR ingradients like '%$keyword%')   AND hide!=1 ORDER BY id        ASC ";


    echo $query2 ;

    $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die('Error, query failed2'); 
    if  (mysql_num_rows($result2)>0){
    mysql_data_seek($result2, 0);   

    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)

    ?>
      <ul id="product-listing">
        <?php

        $i=1;

        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ ?>
        <li <?php  $i; if ($i%3==0) {echo "class=\"last\"";} ?>>
          <div class="img">
            <?php  if ( $row2['new'] ==1 )  { ?>
            <div class="new"><img src="images/new.png" width="18" height="41" /></div>
            <?php  } ?>
            <a href="product-details.php?refID=<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>"> <img src="images/products/284X190/<?php echo $row2['image_1']; ?>" width="284" height="190" alt="" title="" /></a> </div>
          <div class="name"><?php echo $row2['product_name']; ?></div>
          <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="price">Price:
              <?php  if ( $row2['market_price'] !=0 )  { ?>
              <span> $<?php echo $row2['market_price']; ?> </span>
              <?php  } ?>
              $<?php echo $row2['price'];   ?></div>
            <div class="add-to-cart">
              <input type="image" src="images/btn-1.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </form>
        </li>
        <?php  $i++; } ?>
      </ul>
      <?php  } else {  ?>
      No Products,
      <?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a while loop in your php.

```
while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
print_r($item); // echo out whatever you need to for each item returned
}
```

Comment: Yes i used that if i have 10 search result its showing 9  if have 1 result its showing nothing that is the problem

Comment: Why are you using mysql_data_seek? It seems unnecessary, not to mention it is deprecated as of PHP 5.5